# Abount Java Code Design Pattern - Android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, oop, interface, android-alertdialog

I hava some question in Code Design Pattern. I want to use OOP desgin to my code. but I don't how to use that...

Example:

I need a public AlertDialog,but I always use public funtion,likes:

```
public void ShowMsgDialog(String title,String msg)
    {

        AlertDialog.Builder MyAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        MyAlertDialog.setTitle(title);
        MyAlertDialog.setMessage(msg);


        
        MyAlertDialog.setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("reset", (dialog, id) -> {

                    dialog.cancel();
                    txt_PlateNumber.setEnabled(true);
                    txt_Quantity.setEnabled(true);
                    btn_bring.setEnabled(true);

                })
                .setNegativeButton("scan", (dialog, id) -> {
                    txt_PlateNumber.setEnabled(false);
                    txt_Quantity.setEnabled(false);
                    btn_bring.setEnabled(false);
                    dialog.cancel();
                    UnLockCamera();
                });

        MyAlertDialog.show();


    }
```

if I need different event after click,I must make a new function,lead me to have a lot of very similar code...So there is a way to achieve interface a dialog and add different click event? or any better suggestion.
please give me some simple example...Thank you so much

I try use public funtion,but lead me have a bad code

Comment: Is this all about the two buttons (`"reset"` and `"scan"`) or are you talking about dialog events, like *On Cancel* which you can listen to with an [`OnCancelListener`](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)?

Comment: Yes,About two buttons,but I need different buttons tag name and event.

Comment: Apart from the neutral button and some other options, you can build a [custom layout for an `AlertDialog`](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/dialogs#CustomLayout). I think that's the most appropriate way to have a dialog with more than 2 or three buttons.

Comment: To put it simply, when the user encounters situations A and B, button 1, button 2, button 3, and button 4 will appear respectively, and have their own independent events, but if I have 10 dialog boxes, do I have to repeat them 10 times? ?Is there any way to integrate